How to create Cucumber DataTable (not from step) that can be later converted to List<Map<String, String>> using .asMaps(String.class, String.class)
So, i have a method that uses Data Table created via Cucumber
Some step description
 | Role | Name |
 | a1   | x1   |

And inside this method it parses the Data table to this
@AND("Some step description")
public void someStep(DataTable dataTable) {
  ...
  List<Map<String, String>> roles = dataTable.asMaps(String.class, String.class)
  ...
}

Unfortunatly i need to use that method and not as a step which means that i need to create the DataTable and pass it into the method
I tried to create it via DataTable create(List<List<String>> raw) howewer if i create it this way  the dataTable.asMaps(String.class, String.class) fails with Can't convert DataTable to List<Map<class java.lang.String,class java.lang.String>>. DataTable was created without a converter
Is there a way to create the DataTable without the need of a custome converter?
Or maybe an example how to create your own converter?
Tried to use DataTable create(List<List<String>> raw)
Tried to find examples of custom table converter

Cucumber can convert the data table for you. This can be done by replacing the DataTable type with the type you want it converted to i.e. List<Map<String, String>>.
@And("Some step description")
public void someStep(List<Map<String, String>> roles) {
  ...
}

If you have a type that is not supported by Cucumber, then you can use @DataTableType to write a function that does the conversion.
You can then reuse the someStep method by calling it with a List<Map<String, String>> instead of trying to make a DataTable.
For more information it is worth reading: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-java

Oh, interesting.
I would have to rewrite a lot of other persons methods but I like this option way more than what we have currently.

(was late to edit previous one) Thanks, that's interesting.
I mean, it wouldn't work in my case since apparently, my problem was in not creating the DataTable properly (I was creating it without a table converter which meant that the table can't be converted later (to any type pretty much))
But i like this way of getting List<Map<String, String>> way more than writing .asMaps() inside a method. Thanks!

You're not really supposed to create a data table and then convert it. If you're doing that, you might as well create it in the right format straight away. :D

Aaand I'm not sure what what my problem was with this solution last hour, but right now it started working this way:
I saw somewhere that you can create this converter:
private static final DataTableTypeRegistry registry = new DataTableTypeRegistry(Locale.ENGLISH);
private static final TableConverter tableConverter = new DataTableTypeRegistryTableConverter(registry);

and use it when creating a table
List<List<String>> lists = List.of(List.of("key", "value"));
DataTable dataTable = DataTable.create(lists).transpose();

This way it works with dataTable.asMaps(String.class, String.class)
I'm not really sure why it was initially not working this way. I definitely tried it with and without .transpose()
